# libuv: how to start new timer inside handle of other timer

Tags: c, timer, libuv

I use libuv library and I want to run new timer inside handle of other timer:

```
void c2(uv_timer_t* handle) {
    fprintf(stderr, "c2 timer is executing in event-loop... \n");
}

void c3(uv_timer_t* handle) {
    fprintf(stderr, "c3 timer is executing in event-loop... \n");

    uv_timer_t timer2;
    uv_timer_init(uv_default_loop(), &timer2);
    uv_timer_start(&timer2, c2, 5000, 0);
}

int main() {
    uv_loop_t *loop = uv_default_loop();
    uv_loop_init(loop);

    uv_timer_t timer;
    uv_timer_init(loop, &timer);
    uv_timer_start(&timer, c3, 5000, 0);

    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    uv_loop_close(loop);
    free(loop);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect after 5 seconds to see inside console:

```
c3 timer is executing in event-loop...
```

and after 5 seconds later:

```
c2 timer is executing in event-loop...
```

but instead that I see after 5 seconds that c3 timer is executing, and after 5 second later event loop just finish work and I do not see that c2 timer is executing.
I do not understand why and how can I do it?

Comment: Does it help if you call `uv_update_time(uv_loop_t* loop)` in your c3 method?

Comment: Problem wa in timer2 variable. This one have to be global variable. If this one are not global then runtime release memory (stack) after c3() function work.